# Linker Error with AdMob

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to add AdMob to an outdated app however I keep getting the error shown below when I try and build.
[image]

Does anyone know what is causing this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include "StoreKit" and "EventKit" frameworks, to start with.

Go to the portion of your project where frameworks are included, control click on one of the frameworks to bring up a contextual menu where the first choice should be "Show In Finder".  When you show the framework in the Finder, you'll see these additional frameworks that you can drag into the "Frameworks" section of your Xcode project.